# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken): Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi I have rails 5 application which is throwing following errors 
`Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.` `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error when submitting a POST request for signin in staging environment. It's weird because form is working fine for Production and development environment. Here is the request param

```
{  
   "method":"POST",
   "path":"/users/sign_in",
   "format":"html",
   "controller":"Users::SessionsController",
   "action":"create",
   "status":422,
   "error":"ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken",
   "duration":11.53,
   "view":0.0,
   "params":{  
      "utf8":"✓",
      "authenticity_token":"LDPxQ17rH9W/AoW1Hfeyd4in1Ms7snMuys6IyFIlB6K9JoCLanfjHg6OOcqlf/HkE9pPzEuOwVz3d29iwYaJbA==",
      "user":{  
         "email":"",
         "password":"[FILTERED]"
      },
      "commit":"Login"
   },
   "@timestamp":"2018-05-23T12:08:26.463Z",
   "@version":"1",
   "message":"[422] POST /users/sign_in (Users::SessionsController#create)"
}
```

Comment: You are submitting the token correctly, so maybe it's a browser fault? Try doing it in incognito perhaps.

Answer (score -2):

You can add this to the controller

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Of course it's not recommended to do this, but for some reason it solved my problems, since it happen on one form only on my whole application and it was safe to skip this auth.

Comment: Thanks Amir, but I would like to know the real reason for it.

Comment: You're welcome :), Check this out, it should help you https://www.bhalash.com/archives/13544808782

Comment: This will create a big problem with security.

Comment: Exactly, that's why i said its not recommended, just a temp solution